# Unable to Change Background Color of Button in Windows Forms Chess Game

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to change the background color of a button in a Windows Forms Chess game. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
private void AnyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Button clicked!");
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    
    button.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

In my Chess game application, I have an 8x8 grid of buttons, each initially colored white and grey to represent the chessboard. Upon clicking a button (representing a square on the chessboard), I intend to change the background color of the clicked button to blue. However, despite implementing this logic, the button color doesn't change to blue as expected.

I've tried multiple solutions and approaches to change the background color upon button click, but none of them seem to be effective. Could someone provide guidance or suggest a workaround to successfully change the background color of the clicked button to blue within my Windows Forms Chess game?

Comment: It works fine here, in an empty winform the button turns blue. Maybe there is something else going on...

Comment: Are you sure you have assigned the `AnyButtonClick` event handler to all buttons? Put a breakpoint in the code and see if it's getting hit.

Comment: Ensure that the button's `FlatStyle` property is set to `FlatStyle.Flat` or `FlatStyle.Popup` or `FlatStyle.Standard`, as these styles might interfere with the background color change.

Comment: _I've tried multiple solutions and approaches to change the background color upon button click, but none of them seem to be effective._  This is not a helpful statement as this should generally be true of any question asked on Stack Overflow.  Askers are expected to have done some basic debugging and to have made an attempt to solve the problem.  What would be more helpful is if you described, in detail, the attempts you *did* make to solve the problem.  But just saying _I tried multiple solutions and none were effective._ does not add value or detail to your question.

Comment: The problem was I put button.Click += AnyButtonClick inside Form2.cs instead of Form2.Designer.cs